# Java.IO.IOException SendAsync

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, httpclient

Проект на `Xamarin` под `Android`. Последние версии `Xamarin` и `.Net`.

```
private async Task<string> GetStringResponse (string url)
{
    using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
    using (HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(url))
        return await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
}
```

Хочу получить `Json` с сервера, но `GetAsync` выдаёт ошибку:

> [monodroid] Not wrapping exception of type Java.IO.IOException from method `SendAsync`. This will change in a future release.

Без `async/await` еще выдаёт:

> **System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException:** 'Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.'

---

В консольном приложении всё работает, с адресами ошибок нет.

`android.permission.INTERNET` в манифесте есть, проверял.

В интернете не так много случаев этой ошибке, в основном проблема у людей появлялась при переходе версий и было это давно. Их проблема решалась настройкой авейтера `Task.ConfigureAwait(false)`.

`Xamarin` платформа распространённая, но особо проблем с этим не видно, где я так накосячил?

Comment: Xamarin уже устаревает. Я бы советовал щупать его наследника - MAUI.

Comment: По поводу кода, есть шорткат `await client.GetStringAsync(url)`. Плюс, если вдруг не в курсе, клиента достаточно одного (и это рекомендуется мелкомягкими) на всё время работы приложения, то есть его можно закинуть в `static readonly` поле и оттуда пользовать многократно. То есть метод `GetStringResponse` как обёртка получается лишним.

Comment: @aepot, а вот что это такое! Читая доки по `Xamarin`, много раз видел ссылки `.NET MAUI`, но то, что это альтернатива, нигде пока не упоминали. Видимо потому что `Xamarin` пока еще активно поддерживается. `MAUI` ещё и на десктопы, ваще чума, грац!

Comment: Да, MAUI запилен именно на базе Xamarin Forms. Всё так, десктопы тоже может.

Comment: Спамом `HttpClient` и так не грешу, `GetStringResponse` в `for` 'ах не используется) Просто в классе несколько вариантов запроса и выделение повтора строк в отдельный метод напросилось.

Comment: Там более тонкие материи. Диспозить клиент бессмысленно, оно только активные передачи данных рвёт, но подключения не закрывает по факту. Если использовать клиент на запрос, то каждый запрос даже к одному и тому же серваку будет через новое подключение. Если клиент реюзать, то и подключение будет реюзаться, а это + перф по запросам. То есть вся эта история полезна если запросов больше одного на всё время работы. Это ж мобила, берегите ресурс :) Сам клиент потокобезопасен, его можно недумая грузить параллельными запросами.

Comment: Да в [доках](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient?view=net-8.0) в примере кода это сказано: `HttpClient is intended to be instantiated once per application, rather than per-use. See Remarks.` и целая отдельная [статья](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/fundamentals/networking/http/httpclient-guidelines). `IDisposable`, провоцирует людей на `using` , зря они так.

Comment: Ну это значит что перед закрытием приложения его можно со спокойной душой задиспозить. Ну или когда все сетевые дела завершены и он точно больше не понадобится. Я всегда делаю `static readonly` его и не парюсь. `Task` кстати тоже `IDisposable`, а диспозить его не только бесполезно, но и вредно местами. Живите теперь с этим xD

Answer (score 2):

В решении `YourAppName.Android`, `Properties/AssemblyInfo.cs`

Добавить строчку: `[assembly: Application(UsesCleartextTraffic = true)]`

В `AndroidManifest.xml` будет добавляться: `<application ... android:usesCleartextTraffic="True" >`.

---

Теперь мне интересно, почему этого не было по дефолту? Запросы на текста в интернетах, кажется повседневной операцией...